# how to lock an entire database in yii?

Tags: php, database, yii

I want to copy the `database` to another location and I don't want it to be in a middle of another user's `transaction`. Is there a way to lock the `database`?

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

overwrite `getDbConnection()` of **CActiveRecord** and add another property like `private $inUse` then check this if in use,

or have a table for that, but it will be slow to check every time.

Answer (score 0):

I use PostgreSQL. To backup a DB it uses an external tool (pg_dump) who takes a stable and consistent snapshot of the DB. If there is a transaction in progress, the snapshot will have the state before the begin of transaction. I supose that MySQL has a similar tool.

No matter what DB server you use,if you want to know if there is an active transaction, you can use the standard [PDO object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) of your database:

```
$db=Yii::app()->db;
$pdo=$db->getPdoInstance();
if ($pdo->inTransaction(){
   echo "We have an active transaction";
} else {
   echo "Let's start Database dump";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still missing something, let's say I get to the `else` part, who says that exactly then someone isn't starting a transaction?
BTW I'm using SQLite

Comment: You can store in a global parameter --see: [SetGolbalState](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#setGlobalState-detail)-- a flag indicating that database is backingUp and check it in every controller of your app to avoid the acces while this flag is on.